# when value equal 1 after amcharts map area turn black color

Tags: amcharts

When value 1 in amcharts map map area turn black.If there is bigger 1 , it works normally but if there is value=1 in every map area , map areas turn black color.

Here it is I defined map area setting:

```
map.areasSettings = {
    unlistedAreasColor: "#43B1A9",
    rollOverOutlineColor: "#FFFFFF",
    rollOverColor:"#68DFF0", 
    color:"#FFCC00"
        };
```

How can I fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: appears black if all are values are the same, please wait for the next release which will fix this behaviour

Comment: Ok. Thanks. We will wait then